# creating own scripting language in Java desktop app?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a simple web application testing desktop application. I am wondering how I can create my own scripting language for it (Domain Specific Language).

The purpose of this is to offer a very intuitive scripting even for non programmers, and able to define user scenario specific details.

I hope this is clear, basically the question is, how do I create a simple-to-use scripting language that can be translated into Java code.

Perhaps, they can use netbean's IDE to write the scripts.

For ex)

my script:

```
load "http://www.google.com";
click "Search" button;
```

java code:

```
browser.navigate("http://www.google.com";
browser.wait
browser.element("Search").click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to reuse one the existing scripting languages for Java; for example [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/).  Implementing your own scripting language would be whole a lot of work.  And if you've never done any language design and implementation work before the results are likely to be "less than stellar".

> Perhaps, they can use netbean's IDE to write the scripts.

Expecting users of your application (especially non-programmers) to install and use a particular IDE sounds like a really bad idea.

> ... that can be translated into Java code.

Translating to Java code complicates things as well.  It is probably better to *interpret* a scripting language and access Java APIs using a combination of staticly typed method calls and (only where necessary) the Java reflection APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool/framework for languages which extend beyond very simple grammars is to use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). Its a full featured lexer+parser combination, great Java integration, and tons of examples with good documentation.

Do realize that this isn't a trivial project to get right. You should use an existing language if your time is limited